Interpolate heart beats from ECG based on r-peak timestamps
I am trying to interpolate heart beats from an occasionally noisy ECG signal.
This paper finds that it is more accurate to interpolate heart beats from a noisy ECG signal by interpolating on beat timestamp, rather than beat duration. (The latter drifts.)
But I don't know how many heart beats are supposed to be in the noisy regions, so if Y is the heart beat timestamp, I don't know what to pass as X.
Should I create an array with latest heart beat timestamp per original signal 256hz sample? The X as sample index and Y as most recent heart beat timestamp? My ignorant guess is that the shelf changes would throw the cubic spline around. Use weighting to only consider the known timestamps when constructing the spline? I think that'd plot y=x. Do I have no choice but to use interval?

My rambling workings...
My understanding is that they are interpolating the continually increasing raw r-peak timestamp sequence, rather than the fluctuating r-peak interval. I assume X is the heart beat index 1, 2, 3, 4..., and Y is the index of the ECG signal it appears at, say 256, 500, 730... for a ~60bpm 256hz ECG signal.
I am very new to interpolation, and am experimenting with the SciPy interpolate functions CubicSpline or interpolate.splrep and splev.
Or is my approach wrong? The scipy docs recommend np.ma for missing value interpolation, but I can't work out how I would.
A numpy ticket suggests UniVariateSpline with zero knots and zero weights, but if I pass it an array with a nan, spl returns nan for all values. And anyway I still need to know how many heart beats are missing.
y=[1, 4, np.nan, 16, 25, 36, 34, 12, 5, 87]
spl = UnivariateSpline(np.arange(10), y, s=0, w=np.zeros(10))
plt.plot(np.arange(10), spl(np.arange(10)))
>> array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])

I had some luck with zeroing the nans and weights for unknowns:
spl = UnivariateSpline(
        np.arange(10), 
          [1, 4, 0, 16, 25, 36, 34, 12, 5, 87], 
        w=[1, 1, 0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, 1,  1]
)
spl(np.arange(10))
>>> array([ 0.97665691,  4.18844333,  7.52957225, 14.64048455, 26.86293802,
    36.34395811, 32.5930899 , 11.48427138,  6.42129891, 86.48885889])

But I don't know how many nans I have.
Do I need to use intervals when heart beat count is unknown? Intervals at the sample rate, then X is the sample index and Y is the interval?
Could I do the same with heart beat timestamp? The most recent timestamp for each sample, and zero weight for the noisy regions? Is that statistically valid?
Huge thanks for any pointers.

Have you looked into HeartPy? It's a great resource I've used in the past for cleaning up noisy ECG data. It can also help detect heartbeats for BPM.

Thanks for the idea, @amance, I tried neurokit2 and wfdb because this post suggested they were most accurate. But they all seems to do quite a lot of interpolation so I am hoping to tailor my processing to my data (from the NSRR). Given the lack of response I'm guessing I'm missing something fundamental and asking the wrong question.
